How to calculate the precise partition size for a desired displayed size in Windows?
To avoid confusion, let me assure you that this is not about decimal vs binary units.
When I partition a new disk, I like to have nice round figures show in Windows - like 50.0 GB, 300 GB and so on. When I specify the desired space in MBs, the resultant sizes show up as slightly less - like 49.9GB or 299GB.
I assume that this is due to partition metadata overheads stealing a tiny bit of space. I compensate for this by adding a few MBs during partitioning to get the results I want. For example, the C: drive (NTFS) in my boot SSD has 102405 (not 102400) MB in it, and it's displayed as 100 GB.
I've been doing this for a long time. However, I generally arrive at the amount to add by trial and error. Is there a way to calculate the precise amount of space that needs to be added for the purpose?

Part of the issue is that overhead depends on the allocation unit size, so that must be taken into account when figuring how to size the partition. A drive with AU size of 512 bytes stores things differently from one of 4 kB, or 64 kB. Small files are stored more efficiently with small AU size, but the files system itself has greater overhead (more units). See https://superuser.com/questions/31682/what-allocation-unit-size-should-i-use-for-a-drive-with-a-single-ntfs-partitio, for example.

Thanks, but unless I missed something, the link doesn't quite address my question. I'm familiar with cluster/AU size and its effects on speed and space efficiency. I used to be quite conscious about it when storage devices were smaller and slower but haven't thought about it in a long time. Nowadays I usually use the default 4K. Perhaps I should ask how AU size translates to amount of "wasted" overhead space. E.g., a 100GB/4KB partition has 26214400 AUs. How much hidden space does that take away from user space? Are there any other factors?

A long time ago I dove deep into the file systems use on the Amiga, FFS and OFS before anything else appeared. These were relatively simple filesystems, but the allocation was relatively dynamic, so the space required for the metadata grew depending on the folders, files and their sizes. I'd say that filesystems as NTFS, EXT4, ZFS and BTRFS all have a wildly more complex structure, which makes it harder to estimate metadata size, maybe easiest as the partition is "empty" - but still requiring indepth knowledge about actual data structure.

Perhaps I should have made it clearer that I'm asking about the total partition size as displayed by Windows - the space available when the partition is empty. It is always slightly smaller than the raw space allotted to it. I used Amigas too in the 90s. Still miss them.
